# How to ask folder permission in Sandbox in OS X like this window?

Tags: cocoa, sandbox, nsopenpanel, nssavepanel

When it needs folder permission in Sandbox, The Unarchiver will show a window like below.

I can ask permission myself using NSSavePanel, but there is an extra file name text field. If I try NSOpenPanel, the open button is grey. So my question is, can I get the exact window liked below? How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: It seams that there was a deprecated method 
- runModalForDirectory:file:types:
 (OS X v10.6), which is not available in swift.

Answer (score 0):

Now I know how to do.

```
let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
openPanel.directoryURL = self.file.folderURL
openPanel.message = "Need your permission to save to this directory."
openPanel.prompt = "Save"

openPanel.allowedFileTypes = ["none"]
openPanel.allowsOtherFileTypes = false
openPanel.canChooseDirectories = false
openPanel.canChooseDirectories = true

let result = openPanel.runModal()
```

[image]